# Application Keeps Crashing on both phone and android emulator

Tags: android

I am getting an error every time I launch the application both on my phone and android emulator. I received the code from mkyong's website. All I did was change the images that he had to mine. I even named my images the same as his so that I didn't need to change any code.

MainActivity:

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    ImageView image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeImage);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.android3d);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/android" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Image" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
    05-01 12:15:06.140: I/art(1010): Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1717(88KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 67% free, 201KB/623KB, paused 2.035ms total 34.530ms
05-01 12:15:06.171: I/art(1010): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 62(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 73% free, 186KB/698KB, paused 1.067ms total 28.273ms
05-01 12:15:06.230: I/art(1010): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 19(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 74% free, 173KB/685KB, paused 1.064ms total 57.082ms
05-01 12:15:06.231: I/art(1010): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 74MB allocation
05-01 12:15:06.313: I/art(1010): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 74% free, 173KB/685KB, paused 3.133ms total 80.012ms
05-01 12:15:06.314: E/art(1010): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 78298572 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM"
05-01 12:15:06.330: D/skia(1010): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-01 12:15:06.369: D/AndroidRuntime(1010): Shutting down VM
05-01 12:15:06.369: D/AndroidRuntime(1010): --------- beginning of crash
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Process: com.mkyong.android, PID: 1010
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.MyAndroidAppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at com.mkyong.android.MyAndroidAppActivity.onCreate(MyAndroidAppActivity.java:18)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     ... 10 more
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     ... 23 more
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 78298572 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
05-01 12:15:06.401: E/AndroidRuntime(1010):     ... 26 more
05-01 12:16:24.533: I/Process(1010): Sending signal. PID: 1010 SIG: 9
05-01 12:16:30.900: I/art(1158): Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1705(87KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 67% free, 201KB/623KB, paused 1.577ms total 25.822ms
05-01 12:16:30.938: I/art(1158): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 62(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 73% free, 186KB/698KB, paused 1.068ms total 35.500ms
05-01 12:16:31.002: I/art(1158): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 19(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 74% free, 173KB/685KB, paused 1.123ms total 61.584ms
05-01 12:16:31.002: I/art(1158): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 74MB allocation
05-01 12:16:31.067: I/art(1158): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 74% free, 173KB/685KB, paused 1.307ms total 62.638ms
05-01 12:16:31.067: E/art(1158): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 78298572 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM"
05-01 12:16:31.075: D/skia(1158): --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-01 12:16:31.110: D/AndroidRuntime(1158): Shutting down VM
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Process: com.mkyong.android, PID: 1158
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mkyong.android/com.mkyong.android.MyAndroidAppActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageView
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:377)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2144)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at com.mkyong.android.MyAndroidAppActivity.onCreate(MyAndroidAppActivity.java:18)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     ... 10 more
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     ... 23 more
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 78298572 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:973)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2423)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2330)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
05-01 12:16:31.133: E/AndroidRuntime(1158):     ... 26 more
```

Comment: What does _mkyong_ say about it?

Comment: That log cat is not complete. The first part is omitted.

Comment: Can you please post whole logcat, I think there will be Out Of Memory Error, just need to verify it.

Comment: sure, its just heaps so ill have to post it as a comment

Comment: Can you tell me what is the size of image you are using

Answer (score 1):

```
Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 78298572 byte allocation with 524288 free bytes and 31MB until OOM"
```

Error indicates `out of memory` while alloting image to your layout, 
The memory heap size differs between devices, you need to resize down the image, that you are using in your layout. And making several images for different densities can also be helpful.

Comment: What size would you suggest?

Comment: Scale down image for different densities.